# ListView row selector on API level 10?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector

Goal is changing background color of selected row of a ListView. Which I succeed on API level 13 and 16. But same code failed on API level 10 (2.3.3). No exception thrown but not changing color either.

This is what I tried;

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/row_bg_colors"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row_bg_colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/lightBlue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/lightBlue" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/lightBlue" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/lightBlue" android:state_checked="true"/>

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unit_bg"/>

</selector>
```

Very simple adapter which has nothing to do with background. Classic ListView object (not extended). singleChoice attribute on ListView in activity xml file.

There is no warning about compatibility.

So is there a not supported feature I am missing? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Add the list selector to the listview also. That is:

```
<ListView
    android:listSelector="@drawable/row_bg_colors"
/>
```

And also leave the row_bg_colors as background for the linear layout row.

Hope that helps.